# Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './432.jpg'" in conditional rendering

Tags: vue.js

I have a conditional rendering for a profile photo, if there's no picture it will render a default picture, if not, it will render a dynamic one, like this:

```html
<v-avatar class="profile" color="grey" size="164" tile>
     <v-img v-if="card.avatar == ''" :src="require('../../../../public/img/profile/stock-1.jpg')"></v-img>
     <v-img v-else :src="require('../../../../public/img/uploads/avatars/'+card.avatar)"></v-img>
</v-avatar>
```

`card.avatar` is `432.jpg`, however, if I do this

```html
<v-img v-else :src="require('../../../../public/img/uploads/avatars/432.jpg')"></v-img>
```

It works, so the path is definitely right, however I need this one to be dynamic, why it isn't working this way?

Comment: How is this _not_ working? What do you see happen? Is there a broken image? Any errors reported?

Comment: it's literally this error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './432.jpg'"`

Answer (score 0):

If your images are within the `public` folder, you don't need to use `require` since everything in there is bundled automatically.

Try

```html
<v-img v-else :src="`${publicPath}img/uploads/avatars/${cart.avatar}`" />
```

with

```js
data: () => ({
  publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
})
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Comment: I'm using vue with laravel, that's why i have it like that

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference to my answer. If you're trying to use `require`, the images will have to exist when you build your Webpack bundle. If you don't use `require` (as in my answer), then as long as the image exists at the specific path, it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the path directly if you have imgs on public folder:

```html
<v-avatar class="profile" color="grey" size="164" tile>
     <v-img v-if="card.avatar == ''" :src="'/img/profile/stock-1.jpg'"></v-img>
     <v-img v-else :src="'/img/uploads/avatars/' + card.avatar"></v-img>
</v-avatar>
```